# Sliderjs Change text of prev and next button with a data attribute text and in that must show the the previous and next slide data attribute text

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, swiper.js

Like the title, i need to change the next and prev text with the next and prev slide , not the current one that im seen.

on my current slide and in my next and previous button i like to see the text , text-slide , and text-slide

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
loop: true,
spaceBetween: 30,
pagination: {
el: ".swiper-pagination",
},
navigation: {
nextEl: '.next',
prevEl: '.prev',
},
on: {

  init: function() {
updateCaptionText(this);
  },
  activeIndexChange: function() {
updateCaptionText(this);
  }

}

});
```

```
let prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
let next = document.querySelector('.next');

function updateCaptionText(slider) {
    let prev_text = document.querySelector('.prev-text');
    let next_text = document.querySelector('.next-text');
    console.log(slider.slides\[slider.realIndex - 1\]);
    prev_text.innerHTML=slider.slides\[slider.realIndex - 1\].dataset.currentslide
    next_text.innerHTML=slider.slides\[slider.realIndex + 1\].dataset.currentslide
}
```

This is the HTML Markup that im working on

```
    <div class="swiper w-[50%]">
      <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-currentslide="1">
          <div class="flex flex-1 items-start justify-center gap-5 min-h-full">
              <img src="//placehold.it/770x460" alt="" class="rounded-xl" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-currentslide="2">
          <div class="flex flex-1 items-start justify-center min-h-full">
              <img src="//placehold.it/770x460" alt="" class="rounded-xl" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-currentslide="3">
          <div class="flex flex-1 items-start justify-center min-h-full">
              <img src="//placehold.it/770x460" alt="" class="rounded-xl" >
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide" data-currentslide="4">
          <div class="flex flex-1 items-start justify-center min-h-full">
              <img src="//placehold.it/770x460" alt="" class="rounded-xl" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination left-[100px] bottom-40"></div>

    </div>
```

This is the Next and Prev button

```
<div class="">
      <div id="prev" data-prev="" class="bg-red-600 px-5 py-4 inline rounded-full prev"><
      </div>
      <span class="prev-text"> Test </span>
      <span class="next-text"> Test </span>
      <div id="next" data-next="" class="bg-red-600 px-5 py-4 inline rounded-full next"> ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to update the text of the previous and next buttons based on the data attribute of the previous and next slides, not the current one. However, in your current implementation, you're using `slider.realIndex - 1` and `slider.realIndex + 1` which might not always give you the correct indices due to the looping.

In Swiper, when `loop: true` is set, duplicate slides are added to the start and end of the slides array. So, you need to account for these when accessing the slides array.

Here's a modified version of your `updateCaptionText` function that should work:

```js
function updateCaptionText(slider) {
    let prev_text = document.querySelector('.prev-text');
    let next_text = document.querySelector('.next-text');

    let totalSlides = slider.slides.length;
    let realIndex = slider.realIndex;
    let prevIndex = (realIndex === 0) ? totalSlides - 3 : realIndex - 1;
    let nextIndex = (realIndex === totalSlides - 3) ? 0 : realIndex + 1;

    prev_text.innerHTML = slider.slides[prevIndex].dataset.currentslide;
    next_text.innerHTML = slider.slides[nextIndex].dataset.currentslide;
}
```

This code calculates the correct indices for the previous and next slides considering the loop duplicates. It then updates the innerHTML of `prev_text` and `next_text` with the `currentslide` data attribute of the respective slides. Please replace your `updateCaptionText` function with this one and it should work as expected. Remember to remove the `console.log` statement if you don't need it.

Comment: I just tested this and i got this when i load the page,  prev 1 1 next , must be  prev 3 2 next 
when i press the next button , that works , prev appear 1 and next 3 , im looking the slide between,
but when i hit next again , shows 2 an 3 text , and the bullets pagination do not move , in that case i have so see 2 an 1 . because im in the 3º slide.